# Can you add a comma at the end of a line to continue the quotation to the next line?

Tags: commas, quotations

He leaned down whispering,

"Will you stay?"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117749/discussion-on-question-by-saba-p-can-you-add-a-comma-at-the-end-of-a-line-and).

Comment: Commas are not for extended dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be "correct" in formal English, but in fiction or poetry it would be fine, if it's reasonably consistent in with the style in the rest of the piece.  Ie, it's a stylistic choice.